# Remove DataMember by Creating a new base class and obsoleting the derived class

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a class, which I no longer want to use. I have created a base class and made my obsolete class a child of the new, base class.

Data-wise, the only difference between the two classes is a single DataMember property.

I have a class that has a property that referenced derived class in a property (also DataMember). I have replaced that type with the base type.

On deserialization, I get the error message Deserialized object with reference id 'iXX' not found in stream.

If I move the DataMember from my derived class to the base class. The exception goes away.

I know I can't modify the DataContract. I was hoping to create a new class and allow the other, obsolete class to fall off over time.

Can I do this? Why do I get this exception?

*EDIT:
It looks like the xml element has a type attribute when inheritence is involved. I'm guessing that's why the deserialization is failing.

**EDIT:

Serialize with this:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class DerivedType    
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<object,object> DataMemberThatIDoNotNeed { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    //Previously was DerivedType before BaseType was introduced
    public DerivedType MyBaseType { get; set; }      
}
```

Then, deserialize with this:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedType))]
public class BaseType
{

}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]    
public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<object,object> DataMemberThatIDoNotNeed { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    //Previously was DerivedType before BaseType was introduced
    public BaseType MyBaseType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your property is a required part of the contract.

Comment: Why not just mark it as onsolete and create a new API with a class that takes the old class as a constructor parameter?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx

Comment: DataMembers should not be removed from an existing DataContract. This is why I created a new, base class, and marked the old, derived class as obsolete. I also updated any datamembers of the old type to reference the new, base type.

Comment: could you show the code?

Comment: @the_joric the sample has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I executed the following code with your objects:

```
var class1 = new Class1 {MyBaseType = new DerivedType()};

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Class1));
serializer.WriteObject(File.Create(filename), class1);
```

then I changed Class1 to:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public DerivedType MyBaseType { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code still works:

```
var readObject = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Class1)).ReadObject(File.OpenRead(filename));

readObject.Should().NotBeNull(); // it is not null
```

Maybe you need to show your serialization code to add more specifics.

Comment: Class1 should use DerivedType to start, and you need to load the property DataMemberThatIDoNotNeed with some data. Then change from DerivedType to BaseType and deserialize The serialization from before. It should break.

Comment: I have modified the code to show the classes at serialization, and the new/modified classes at deserialization

Comment: What the cob?! When serializing, did you have data in the DataMemberThatIDoNotNeed DataMember? Also, the BaseType class should not have been apart of the model. Then you need to introduce the BaseType class and try to deserialize. Are you sure that didn't work?

Comment: yes, I used your objetc definitions, crated and populated the data, then executed code to serialize, changed definitions and finally deserialized. `DataMemberThatIDoNotNeed` got populated, no any error occured. could you should your serialization/deserialization code?

Comment: Well, I don't know. I just tried it again and everything seems to work. I guess I was just doing something wrong...